# jQuery, javascript unload

Tags: javascript, jquery, request

I have a function:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    $.get("Handler.ashx", "mode=saveuser&user=" + $("#username").text(), function (text) { });
};
```

But the page unloads before the request has time to execute.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't make your request asynchronous, ie:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    $.ajax("Handler.ashx", {
        data: "mode=saveuser&user=" + $("#username").text(),
        success: function (text) { },
        async: false
    );
};
```

Comment: @lis.sanLee you're welcome. If an answer has helped solve your problem, [don't forget to thank the user by clicking the green checkmark next to it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/158105).